# always failed to send image using telegram API

Tags: php

i want to create an app with telegram api and codeigniter. when i try to send image or others file, i get some error like this :

Message: file_get_contents(''): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request

my controller is like this :

```
public function index()
{

this->tele = new telegramBot('token');

$path= base_url().'assets/maldini.png';
$info = $this->tele->sendPhoto('chati_id',$path);
print_r($info);
    $this->load->view('tes');
 }
}
```

how to solve this? thanks in advance :)

Comment: syntax error with an extra } and what library "telegramBot" come from?

Comment: the last " } " for close the main class sir, and telegramBot is library from here : https://github.com/mgp25/Telegram-Bot-API

Answer (score 0):

if you use this lib https://github.com/TelegramBot/Api, it's working code:

```
$chat_id = <chat_id>;
$token = <token>;
$bot = new \TelegramBot\Api\BotApi($token);

try {

    $bot->sendPhoto($chat_id, <file_id>, 'caption');

    //or if you file is local
    //$bot->sendPhoto($chat_id, new \CurlFile(<local_file.jpg>), 'caption');

} catch (\TelegramBot\Api\Exception $e) {

    $e->getMessage();

}
```

if not, this is simple GET method:

```
https://api.telegram.org/bot<token>/sendPhoto?chat_id=<chat_id>&photo=<file_id>
```

more info [Telegram Bot API](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#sendphoto)